# Magento backend login error

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, php-5.4

I accidentally deleted `admin_user` **table** and when I created it again, I'm unable to access the backend. It keeps throwing the error page with a new report number every time. On checking `var/reports`, it shows :

> "Role id 'G1' already exists in the registry";i:1;s:2565:"#0
>   /home/cpanel/public_html/lib/Zend/Acl.php(160):
>   Zend_Acl_Role_Registry->add(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_Group),
>   NULL)

What should I do now ? I'm completely unable to access the backend.

Comment: Try to clean cache and session

Answer (score 0):

Clean and flush the `cache` and `session`.